# Navigation Pane folder hierarchy expands while browsing Win8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer

How do I prevent the folders in the navigation pane from expanding while browsing folders in the main pane? I want to collapse and expand folders regardless of where I am in the main pane.

I am using the Classic Shell Start Menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I prevent the folders in the navigation pane from expanding?

> I want to collapse and expand folders regardless of where I am in the main pane.

Disable "Automatically expand to current folder":

- Menu bar > "View" > "Options" > "General" tab > "Navigation Pane" > uncheck "Automatically expand to current folder"
- Click "OK"

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's amusing how you edited my question to add the "Windows 8.1" tag when your answer has nothing to do with Windows 8.1. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @AzulShiva Hehe. The answer is correct - they just moved the option in Windows 8.1 :) Thanks for the edit.